# Search post by tag name, return post with all related tags in one query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have three tables.

posts

| post_id | post_content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alpha |
| 2 | Beta |

post_tags

| post_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

tags

| tag_id | tag_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dogs |
| 2 | Cats |

Is it possible in Postgres to make a query to return post 1 from posts and both of its tags if all I know is one of its tags.

I tried to accomplish this with the following query, with no success:

```
SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_content, tags.tag_name
FROM posts
JOIN posts_tags
ON posts.post_id = post_tags.post_id 
JOIN tags
ON post_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id
WHERE tags.tag_name = Dogs;
```

I am expecting to get the following result set

| post_id | post_content | tag_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alpha | Dogs |
| 1 | Alpha | Cats |

How should I modify my query to accomplish this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query doesn't work because you filter directly on your joined table, thus picking only those records that satisfy the condition (`WHERE tags.tag_name = Dogs`).

Instead you could first find what are the "*post_id*"s that have that "*tag_name*", then filter the results of your join operations.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT pt.post_id,
           p.post_content,
           t.tag_name
    FROM       posts p
    INNER JOIN post_tags pt
            ON p.post_id = pt.post_id
    INNER JOIN tags      t
            ON pt.tag_id = t.tag_id
)
SELECT post_id, post_content, tag_name
FROM       cte
INNER JOIN (SELECT post_id FROM cte WHERE tag_name = 'Dogs') dogs_tagged
        ON cte.post_id = dogs_tagged.post_id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gTUmYDpzk8mpYEZ1JkpFHx/1).

Comment: Is it possible to do it without a CTE?

Comment: Yes but becomes definitevely more inefficient. Do you really need it?

Comment: Yes, I do. Only for learning though.

Comment: It's sufficient to substitute every instance of cte with the corresponding cte code >> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gTUmYDpzk8mpYEZ1JkpFHx/2. As you can see, this leads you to computing the subquery and all joins twice.